# Chart.js how to remove final label on chart

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

I have an issue on my x-axis where the label for the max value I have set overlaps with the previous label. How can I prevent the final label from being displayed?

[image]

I have looked at all of the properties within the NestedTickoptions, TickOptions and LinearTickOption interfaces (I'm using type script) but none of the options appear to help me. Will I have to write some custom functionality within a callback?

Comment: you could round up the max value of the x-axis to the next "tick"

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that? The tick increments are auto defined therefore unsure how to determine the value of the next tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `callback` function to add labels on `xAxes`. Idea is to not display last label, see code sample:

```
ticks: {
    callback: function(value, index, values) {
        var lastValue = values[values.length - 1];
        var displayValue = value === lastValue ? '' : lastValue;
        return displayValue;
    }
}
```

in callback functions you get all labels what you have, just add this to `xAxes`.

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        // ticks
}],
```